# Page Object design pattern best practice in Selenium

Tags: design-patterns, selenium, pageobjects

So, I read that the best practice in PageObject design pattern is to design it with "User service" in mind than "User Action". I am having a hard time trying to decide how much I should break down / not in a user service.

For example, I have a scenario which consists of multiple user services. and let's say some user service could consists up to 20 steps of user actions, and some of the user actions might involve some logic implementation (say, going through selection, or go through a few modals, etc). I am not comfortable combining all those actions into one single user service. So I try to break it down into mini-'complex actions'. But then i feel doing it that way is making my design pattern a little inconsistent, and might end up harder to understand for other coders to read / understand my intention. I am tempted to write it in 'user action'-oriented way, but then it seems like it is against the recommended best practice.

When do you decide which complex action should be refactored out, which should not? And how do you structure your tests (from action level, to a high level scenario)?

Btw, I am using Ruby and Selenium-webdriver to test web-application.

Comment: Perhaps give more concrete examples of your "user actions". The Page Object pattern is meant to represents *services* your page offers. That is to say your page offers the ability to *login* rather than the ability to fill in the username & password fields and then click Login.

Comment: Hm, let's say I want to test a service to order food online. And the Order page has a lot of fields to fill and various extras and whatnot to select from. And depending on what you click on, modals may even pop up that require more than a click interaction. In that case, would designing it in 'user action' way more modular? Like, i have separate methods that click each different extras, select date/time, fill payment fields, fill user info fields, handle modal A if action A is selected, or handle modal B if action B is selected. That way when I design my test, I can vary my actions.Suggestion?